# Distribute number of CPU cores per instance in a VM

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm running two separate instances of SQL Server 2012 in a VM that has 8 cores. How do I tell each instance to use only 2 cores (or any number) to be compliant with the per core licensing model?

Is the Affinity Mask setting used for this purpose?

I'm guessing this is not possible and that I would have to license the entire 8 cores whether or not they're used but need a confirmation.

Thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 0):

Using the affinity mask is the correct way to do this. For each instance, turn off the automatic allocation, then check (in your case) the two CPU cores you want to use for each instance.

Comment: This will not affect licensing at all. You still need to license the number of cores assigned to the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer and thought someone else might benefit from it.

Affinity mask has nothing to do with licensing. The number of cores assigned to a VM must be licensed for a production load no matter what.

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: If this answers to your question, please accept it.